# Patch global variable once in several modules

Tags: python, patch, python-unittest, monkeypatching, python-unittest.mock

Imagine that we have a module `one.py` with some global variable `glob_var=object()`.
Also I have some other modules on different levels that import `glob_var` using relative import, such as:

- `from .one.py import glob_var`
- `from ..one.py import glob_var`
- `from ...one.py import glob_var`

I want to patch this `glob_var` once, instead of patching three times for those modules that imports the variable. Is it possible to implement?

P.S. It's not necessarily to be a global variable. It can be a function or other object

Comment: Make a setter function for it, import and call it in any module that you want to patch from.

Comment: Why are you testing several modules at once? It sounds like your design doesn't isolate them sufficiently.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the reason that I have some big project, and this `glob_var` is an instance of some class that makes some stuff that slows down my testing and I just want to patch it when debugging functionality.

Comment: *"some class that makes some stuff"*?! Any chance of a [mcve]?